# Wordpress image remove width parameter from url and remove height width tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded few images to **wordpress** and the image in slider comes with **550px** only.
While my original width of the image is **1024px**.

So wordpress is making the url something like this :

```
 <img class="amazingslider-img-elem-3" data-originalwidth="550" data-originalheight="217" style="position:absolute;max-width:100%;width:100%;height:auto;left:0%;top:0%;margin-top:0.09728867623604587%;" src="http://i0.wp.com/uwf.org.in/jibaint/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/slider1.jpg?w=550">
```

so i want to remove this high lighted tags and parameters in url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered very well over on Wordpress Stack Exchange. You can read more here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29881/stop-wordpress-from-hardcoding-img-width-and-height-attributes

There are 2 main approaches. The first is that when you retrieve the image, rather than using `get_the_post_thumbnail` that you get the attachment id and then you can get the source and change the markup yourself

The second may be the solution for you - it's a change to override the default image markup that Wordpress uses by **replacing/overriding** the `image_downsize` function.

Both of those approaches are very well explained on the link I mentioned above